# How to assign attribute to the product without attribute set in magento

Tags: magento

I want to assign the attribute value  to the product page in the **catalog->manage products** without assigning into attribute set in magento.

Is it possible to do like this in **magento 1.8**? If yes,how to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: An attribute without attribute set! why do you need that?

Comment: you mean, want to assign that attribute to all attribute sets? (automatically assign to all attribute sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is not really clear, but I hope I understood correctly.
You cannot assign attributes directly to the product.
There is direct relation between a product and an attribute entities. 
A product can have a certain attribute value. That's it.

Even if you insert the value for that attribute manually in the correct table it will be useless.
That value will be a zombie value. It will be ignored by the application and it will only take up space in your db.

The design of the app is like this.

An attribute set contains attributes (in a many to many relation).
A product has an attribute set as a parent entity (so one to many relation).
A product can have values for the attributes in the attribute set it is assigned to.